# How to "Create Your Own Search Provider" in IE9 and later?

Tags: internet-explorer-9

We used to be able to add a custom search provider in Internet Explorer to search any site that put search words in the query string (such as in StackExchange sites). The page where that it was done was

http://www.ieaddons.com/gb/createsearch.aspx

However, this page now redirects to a generic IE Gallery page.

When I upgraded from IE8 to IE9, my StackOverflow provider carried over, but I recently reset my browser settings and am not able to get it back.

Can we easily create a custom search provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, but the favicon isn't currently working. Just add this to a .reg file to add it to the registry. You'll need to create a GUID:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\SearchScopes\{generate a guid to put here}]
"DisplayName"="Stackoverflow"
"URL"="http://stackoverflow.com/search?q={searchTerms}"
"ShowSearchSuggestions"=dword:00000001
"FaviconURL"="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico"
```

You should be able to alter this to use for searching other sites.

Answer (score 4):

The link didn't survive the site redesign, according to the [IEinternals Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/04/28/building-custom-search-providers-for-the-internet-explorer-search-box.aspx) but the original code is still active and hosted at http://www.enhanceie.com/ie/searchbuilder.asp .

Comment: I've just tried this with Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 7, and nothing happens when I fill in the form and click "Install" on that page. Does it work for anyone else, or have Microsoft dumbed-down IE to the stage where you can no longer add search provider?